# Order of generators in infinite cyclic group.

Tags: group-theory

I read that order of generators in an infinite cyclic group can be 0 or $\infty$. I understand how it is infinity but I don't get how can the order of a generator be 0.

Can someone please help me understand the above statement ?

Comment: An element of order zero cannot generate anything of order greater than zero...What did you **actually** meant to ask?

Comment: I think you may have wanted to ask or find out why the order of **any** element in an infinite cyclic group is either zero or infinity (if writtent additively), or 1 or infinite (if written multiplicatively), or in other words: the order of **any** non-unit (additive or multiplicative) element in an infinite cyclic group is infinite.

Comment: I was reading this proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134410/an-infinite-cyclic-group-has-exactly-two-generators which says $a^0 = e$ for infinite cyclic group. So it means that order of generator (a) is 0 right  ?

Comment: Where does it say this? The answer is not saying such a thing!

Comment: See the statement in brackets.

Comment: @Rajesh No. The equation $\;a^0=e=\;$ the group's unit, is true in **any** group, whether finite, infinite, cyclir , etc. (Written multiplicatively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An infinite cyclic group $G=\langle a \rangle $ has exactly two generators, namely $a$ and $a^{-1}$. By definition, the order of an element is the smallest *positive* exponent $n\ge 1$ with $a^n=e$, or infinity.

References:

[Orders of Elements in a Group](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/order.pdf)

[An Infinite Cyclic Group has Exactly Two Generators: Is My Proof Correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075889/an-infinite-cyclic-group-has-exactly-two-generators-is-my-proof-correct)

Comment: I was reading this proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134410/an-infinite-cyclic-group-has-exactly-two-generators which says $ a^0= e $ for infinite cyclic group. So it means that order of generator (a) is 0 right ?

Comment: So what will be the order of generator?

Comment: Infinity, as it is defined, see K. Conrad's notes.

Comment: Comment under my question says $a^0 = e$ is true for any group. So is it true even for infinite cyclic group? I am not understanding the meaning of raising the power of a generator to 0

Comment: There are two different statements here. First, the order of a group element is **positive**, or infinity, hence not zero. Second, $a^0$ is defined to be $1$.

Comment: So $a^0 =1 $ and $a^1 = a$ for every group right ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can also write $e$ for the neutral element.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.